# Updating database through HTML and SQL alchemy form not working

Tags: python, html, sqlite, sqlalchemy

Through debugging I've found that the function is not reaching the if statement, but I can't figure out how to fix this issue, I'm guessing that the form isn't calling upon the function properly but can't figure out why.

This is the table I'm adding the data to

```
class Game(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'games'
    ID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True)
    dateadded = db.Column(db.Date)
    useradded = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('userinfo.username'))
    description = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True)
    datepublished = db.Column(db.Date)
    publisher = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('publishers.publishername'))
    developer = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('developers.developername'))
    developer1 = db.relationship('Developer', primaryjoin='Game.developer == Developer.developername', backref='games')
    publisher1 = db.relationship('Publisher', primaryjoin='Game.publisher == Publisher.publishername', backref='games')
    userinfo = db.relationship('Userinfo', primaryjoin='Game.useradded == Userinfo.username', backref='games')
```

the HTML form

```
{% if session.get('user') %}
<br>
<form method="POST" name="creategame" action="/creategame">
    <input type="text" name="gamename" placeholder="game name">
    <input type="text" name="description" placeholder="game description">
    <input type="date" name="datepublished" placeholder="date published">
    <input type="text" name="publisher" placeholder="publisher">
    <input type="text" name="developer" placeholder="developer">
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ request.path }}" name="from"> 
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Add Game">
</form>
{% endif %}
<br>
```

the Python sqlalchemy function

```
@app.route('/creategame', methods=["POST"])
def creategame():
    user=current_user()
    if user:
        new_game = Game()
        new_publisher = Publisher()
        new_developer = Developer()
        new_game.name = request.form.get('gamename')
        new_game.dateadded = datetime.datetime.now()
        #new_game.dateadded = str(new_game.dateadded)
        #new_game.dateadded = new_game.dateadded.split(" ")
        #new_game.dateadded.pop(1)
        #new_game.dateadded = str(new_game.dateadded)
        #print(new_game.dateadded)
        new_game.useradded = current_user()
        new_game.description = request.form.get('description')
        new_game.datepublished = request.form.get('datepublished')
        new_game.publisher = request.form.get('publisher')
        new_publisher.publishername == new_game.publisher
        new_game.developer = request.form.get('developer')
        new_developer.developername == new_game.developer
        print(new_game.name, new_game.dateadded, new_game.useradded, new_game.description, new_game.datepublished, 
        new_game.publisher, new_game.developer) # debug
        if request.form.get('creategame'):
            print(new_game.name, new_game.dateadded, new_game.useradded, new_game.description, new_game.datepublished, 
            new_game.publisher, new_game.developer) # debug
            print("here the second") # debug
            db.session.add(new_developer)
            db.session.commit()
            db.session.add(new_publisher)
            db.session.commit()
            db.session.add(new_game)
            db.session.commit()
    return redirect(request.form.get('from', '/'))
```

Comment: What are you expecting `request.form.get('creategame')` to return when that's not a field _within_ the form?

Comment: thanks for clarifying how that works, how would i make it a field within the form?

Comment: nevermind realised how much of an idiot i am

Comment: Please do not call yourself an idiot. If you have found a solution that will help other people you can post an answer. If you found a typo or realized your question was invalid you can always delete it

Answer (score 0):

changed:

```
if request.form.get('creategame'):
```

to:

```
if request.form.get('gamename'):
```

so that there was actually a field to trigger the if statement